# Choosing whether to remove ads or not

Tags: feature-request, privileges, advertising

I just hit 200 reputations and saw big ads removed.

But they didn't bother me at all, so I would like to get them back to support the site.

Is there any way to do so ?

Comment: Browse incognito, or with a low rep sock. If you see something you want to upvote/downvote/comment/answer etc switch back to your main account. ;)